# Why does this equivalent program not compile?

Tags: haskell, impredicativetypes

This program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ImpredicativeTypes #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive

unsafeModify :: [(forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())] -> V.Vector Int -> V.Vector Int
unsafeModify mods vec = runST $ do
    mvec <- V.unsafeThaw vec
    (mods !! 0) mvec
    V.unsafeFreeze mvec
```

Compiles. This program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ImpredicativeTypes #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive

unsafeModify :: [(forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())] -> V.Vector Int -> V.Vector Int
unsafeModify mods vec = runST $ do
    mvec <- V.unsafeThaw vec
    ($ mvec) (mods !! 0)
    V.unsafeFreeze mvec
```

Does not compile with the following error:

```
Muts.hs:10:15:
    Couldn't match type ‘forall s1. UV.MVector s1 Int -> ST s1 ()’
                  with ‘UV.MVector s Int -> ST s a0’
    Expected type: [UV.MVector s Int -> ST s a0]
      Actual type: [forall s. UV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()]
    Relevant bindings include
      mvec :: UV.MVector s Int (bound at Muts.hs:9:5)
    In the first argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘mods’
    In the first argument of ‘$ mvec’, namely ‘(mods !! 0)’
```

Why?

Comment: What error does the second one give?

Comment: Question updated. Sorry.

Comment: Basically due to the `forall` Rank2Type in your list. `$` has the (explicit) type `forall a b. (a -> b) -> a -> b`, and `(a -> b)` isn't compatible to `forall s. MV.Vector s Int -> St s ()`. See [this article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/explicit-forall#rankntypes--rank2types--and-polymorphiccomponents) for a quick overview of RankNTypes.

Comment: `ImpredicativeTypes` doesn't actually work. If GHC suggests using it, don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Note: This post is written in literate Haskell. You can save it as Unsafe.lhs and try it in your GHCi.</sub>

---

Let's compare the types of the different lines:

```
 mods                ::     [(forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())]
(mods !! 0)          ::      (forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())
(mods !! 0)  mvec    ::       forall s. ST s ()


($ mvec)             ::     (MV.Vector s Int -> b) -> b
         (mods !! 0) ::     (forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())
($ mvec) (mods !! 0) ::     ????????????????????????
```

They aren't equivalent due to `$`'s type:

```
($) :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Whereas you would need something along

```
($)  :: (a ~ (forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())) =>
      (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

which isn't legal.

However, let's have a look at what you actually want to do.

```
> {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

> import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
> import qualified Data.Vector as V
> import Control.Monad.ST
> import Control.Monad.Primitive

  unsafeModify :: ??? -> V.Vector Int -> V.Vector Int

> unsafeModify mods vec = runST $ do
>   mvec <- V.unsafeThaw vec
>   mapM_ ($ mvec) (mods !! 0)
>   V.unsafeFreeze mvec
```

Things got messy due to `unsafeModify`'s polymorphic first argument `mods`. Your original type

```
[(forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())]
```

tells us it is a list of functions, where every function is polymorphic the parameter `s`, so every function *could use another `s`*. However, that's too much. It's fine if the `s` gets shared throuhgout the whole list:

```
(forall s. [MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()])
```

After all, we want to use all functions in the same `ST` computation, therefore the type of the stream state token `s` can be the same. We end up with

```
> unsafeModify :: (forall s. [MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()]) -> V.Vector Int -> V.Vector Int
```

And now your code happily compiles, regardless of whether you use `($ mvec) (mods !! 0)`, `(mods !! 0) mvec` or `mapM_`, because `s` is now correctly fixed by `runST` throughout the whole list.

Comment: The `????` part begs the question: why doesn't GHC instantiate the `s` in the polytype for `(mods !! 0)` to be the same as the (rigid) `s` in the type of `($ mvec)`? After all, when we do `(+) (length []) 10` the polytype of `10` gets instantiated correctly to `Int`.

Comment: `$` gets its own special case in the type checker.

Answer (score 3):

(This should probably be a comment, but I need more space.)

Sadly, impredicative types do not work very well in GHC, as @dfeuer pointed out.
Consider this example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes, PartialTypeSignatures #-}
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import Control.Monad.ST

-- myIndex :: [forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()] 
--         -> Int
--         -> (forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())
myIndex = (!!) :: [forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()] -> Int -> _
```

It compiles successfully, albeit with a warning due to the type hole:

```
VectorTest.hs:9:69: Warning:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()
    Relevant bindings include
      myIndex :: [forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()]
                 -> Int -> forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()
        (bound at VectorTest.hs:9:1)
```

We could try to remove the `PartialTypeSignatures` extension and fill the hole with its type `forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()`. But this fails horribly:

```
VectorTest.hs:9:11:
    Couldn't match type ‘forall s2. MV.MVector s2 Int -> ST s2 ()’
                   with ‘MV.MVector s1 Int -> ST s1 ()’
    Expected type: [forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()]
                   -> Int -> MV.MVector s1 Int -> ST s1 ()
      Actual type: [MV.MVector s1 Int -> ST s1 ()]
                   -> Int -> MV.MVector s1 Int -> ST s1 ()
```

The last `forall` gets hoisted to the top-level, and now GHC infers that the first argument of `(!!)` must a be a list of monomorphic elements `[MV.MVector s1 Int -> ST s1 ()]` *despite* our annotation! Basically, GHC has two choices:

```
-- Note the hoisted forall s1
myIndex = (!!) :: forall s1. [forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()] -> Int 
               -- ^ first choice for instantiating the type of (!!)
               -> MV.MVector s1 Int -> ST s1 ()
               -- ^ second choice
```

GHC chooses the second, and fails. Only with a partial type signature I was able to remove the second choice so that GHC was forced to do the right thing.

If only we had explicit type application like in GHC Core, we could have written `(!!) @ (forall s. ...)`, but alas we have not.